# Jquery change the class of a div issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the class os an element which is `icon-local` to `icon-local-img` by adding the `-img` to the end of the class.

Here is what I am trying. Why is it not working?

HTML

```
<div class="icon-local">sdvdfvsdfvdfs fdsfggfd</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon-local {
    color:#00f;
}
.icon-local-img {
    color:#f00;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function swapClass($obj) {
        $($obj).toggleClass($obj + ' ' + $obj + '-img');
    }
    if (!$('html').hasClass('fontface')) {
        swapClass('icon-local');
        swapClass('icon-mail');
        swapClass('icon-phone');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ka5g/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/x8J4B/)

```
function swapClass($obj) {
    $('.' + $obj).toggleClass($obj + ' ' + $obj + '-img');
     //^ class selector
}
```

[Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)